# Implementing PageMenu / initializing view controllers from storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard

I'm trying to get this pod working in my project and I'm stuck on understanding how this bit works :

https://github.com/uacaps/PageMenu

```
// Create variables for all view controllers you want to put in the 
// page menu, initialize them, and add each to the controller array. 
// (Can be any UIViewController subclass)
// Make sure the title property of all view controllers is set
// Example:
var controller : UIViewController = UIViewController(nibName: "controllerNibName", bundle: nil)
controller.title = "SAMPLE TITLE"
controllerArray.append(controller)
```

I've seen things that say I need to initialize the view controller with the storyboard ID I set in the storyboard , but when I try to do somethign like

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "MyStoryboardName", bundle: nil)
let vc =      storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("someViewController") as! UIViewController
self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

But to be honest I have no idea where/when to put that/ if that's even what

The idea is to make an array of view controllers for the pagemenu to display with the tab bar up at the top, but I'm not sure how exactly to make that array from views I'm making in the storyboard.

Comment: hii @Nichole H i m facing one issue ...when i trying to go to child view controller on button click from ViewController which is added to PageMenu it takes time help me with this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go. PageMenu is super cool and super customizable. Have fun. Hope this helps. Let me know if you run into any other problems.

```
var pageMenu: CAPSPageMenu?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    setupPages()
}    

func setupPages() {

    var controllerArray: [UIViewController] = []

    let firstVC = FirstViewController()
    firstVC.title = "FirstOne"

    let secondVC = SecondViewController()
    secondVC.title = "Another One"

    let thirdVC = ThirdViewController()
    thirdVC.title = "And Another One"

    controllerArray.append(firstVC)
    controllerArray.append(secondVC)
    controllerArray.append(thirdVC)

    // a bunch of random customization
    let parameters: [CAPSPageMenuOption] = [
        .ScrollMenuBackgroundColor(UIColor.quotesBackgroundColor()),
        .ViewBackgroundColor(UIColor.quotesBackgroundColor()),
        .SelectionIndicatorColor(UIColor.peterRiverColor()),
        .BottomMenuHairlineColor(UIColor(red: 70.0/255.0, green: 70.0/255.0, blue: 80.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)),
        .MenuHeight(40.0),
        .MenuItemWidth(100.0),
        .CenterMenuItems(true),
        .SelectedMenuItemLabelColor(UIColor.blueColor())
        ]

    pageMenu = CAPSPageMenu(viewControllers: controllerArray, frame: CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height), pageMenuOptions: parameters)

    self.view.addSubview(pageMenu!.view)

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Modification to above answer if you are using storyboardIds for viewcontroller instantiation.

```
var pageMenu: CAPSPageMenu?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    setupPages()
}    

func setupPages() {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "MyStoryboardName", bundle: nil)

    var controllerArray: [UIViewController] = []

    let firstVC = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("FirstViewControlleridentifier") as! FirstViewController
    firstVC.title = "FirstOne"

    let secondVC = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SecondViewControlleridentifier") as! SecondViewController
    secondVC.title = "Another One"

    let thirdVC = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ThirdViewControlleridentifier") as! ThirdViewController
    thirdVC.title = "And Another One"

    controllerArray.append(firstVC)
    controllerArray.append(secondVC)
    controllerArray.append(thirdVC)

    // a bunch of random customization
    let parameters: [CAPSPageMenuOption] = [
        .ScrollMenuBackgroundColor(UIColor.quotesBackgroundColor()),
        .ViewBackgroundColor(UIColor.quotesBackgroundColor()),
        .SelectionIndicatorColor(UIColor.peterRiverColor()),
        .BottomMenuHairlineColor(UIColor(red: 70.0/255.0, green: 70.0/255.0, blue: 80.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)),
        .MenuHeight(40.0),
        .MenuItemWidth(100.0),
        .CenterMenuItems(true),
        .SelectedMenuItemLabelColor(UIColor.blueColor())
        ]

    pageMenu = CAPSPageMenu(viewControllers: controllerArray, frame: CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height), pageMenuOptions: parameters)

    self.view.addSubview(pageMenu!.view)

}
```

Comment: hii @Aks i m facing one issue ...when i trying to go to child view controller on button click from ViewController which is added to PageMenu it takes time help me with this

Comment: Please post complete information. Will not be able to help with this little and unclear info.

Comment: suppose i have a pagemenu tab with two viewcontrollers.... in one of the view controller their is a button so when i click to that button i m navigating to child viewcontroller but child view taking more time to load what issue could u help

Comment: Please provide a sample project or code for what have you tried. Not possible to do a private chat, sorry.

Comment: DispatchQueue.main.async {
            
            let findLocation = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FindViewController") as! FindViewController
            findLocation.LocationFindSingelDict = self.ResultSingelDict
            findLocation.parentNavigationController = self.navigationController
            self.parentNavigationController?.pushViewController(findLocation, animated: true)
        }

this what i have tried it is navigating but takes time

Answer (score 3):

Updated Swift-3 Version of **David**

> Podfile for Swift-3
>     pod 'PageMenu' , :git =>
>   'https://github.com/orazz/PageMenu'

```
func setupPages() {
    var controllerArray: [UIViewController] = []
    let firstVC = FirstVC()
    firstVC.title = "First"
    let secondVC = SecondVC()
    secondVC.title = "Second"
    let thirdVC = ThirdVC()
    thirdVC.title = "Third"

    controllerArray.append(firstVC)
    controllerArray.append(secondVC)
    controllerArray.append(thirdVC)

    let parameters: [CAPSPageMenuOption] = [
        .scrollMenuBackgroundColor(.blue),
        .viewBackgroundColor(.white),
        .selectionIndicatorColor(.white),
        .bottomMenuHairlineColor(.white),
        .menuHeight(40.0),
        .menuItemWidth(self.view.frame.width/3),
        .centerMenuItems(true),
        .selectedMenuItemLabelColor(.white),
        .unselectedMenuItemLabelColor(.white),
        .menuMargin(0.0)
    ]

    pageMenu = CAPSPageMenu(viewControllers: controllerArray, frame: CGRect(x:0,y:64,width:self.view.frame.width ,height:self.view.frame.height) , pageMenuOptions: parameters)
     self.view.addSubview(pageMenu!.view)
}
```

Comment: Hi, i am facing one issue.if i open gallery from this page menu based view controller and if i come back then page menu is not appearing.

Answer (score 1):

An updated Swift-3 version of **Shrawn**
compatible with an iPhone-X simulator

```
func setupPages() {

var controllerArray: [UIViewController] = []
let firstVC = FirstVC()
firstVC.title = "First"
let secondVC = SecondVC()
secondVC.title = "Second"
let thirdVC = ThirdVC()
thirdVC.title = "Third"

controllerArray.append(firstVC)
controllerArray.append(secondVC)
controllerArray.append(thirdVC)

let parameters: [CAPSPageMenuOption] = [
    .scrollMenuBackgroundColor(.blue),
    .viewBackgroundColor(.white),
    .selectionIndicatorColor(.white),
    .bottomMenuHairlineColor(.white),
    .menuHeight(40.0),
    .menuItemWidth(self.view.frame.width/3),
    .centerMenuItems(true),
    .selectedMenuItemLabelColor(.white),
    .unselectedMenuItemLabelColor(.white),
    .menuMargin(0.0)
]

pageMenu = CAPSPageMenu(viewControllers: controllerArray, frame: CGRect(x:0,y:(self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.maxY)!,width:self.view.frame.width ,height:self.view.frame.height), pageMenuOptions: parameters)

    self.view.addSubview(pageMenu!.view)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use this repo  .It is so much simpler and easily understandable for RnD. (Swift 3 code)

https://github.com/lakshikabhardwaj/LBViewControllerCollection

```
  let mainViewController = CPPageMenuVC(nibName: "CPPageMenuVC", bundle: nil)
  let pageMenuarray :[PageModal] = [PageModal(pageTitle: "Cat", pageVC: cpCatVC),PageModal(pageTitle: "Cow", pageVC: cowCX),PageModal(pageTitle: "Chat", pageVC: cpCatVC),PageModal(pageTitle: "ElephantElephant", pageVC: elephantVC)]

  pageMenuVC.pageArray = pageMenuarray
```

Comment: your library need to be updated. Not working properly. Please check.