# Using PageMenu with Storyboards Swift 3

Tags: ios, github, swift3, cocoapods

I'm trying to use [this](https://github.com/uacaps/PageMenu) repo to create a PageMenu like you'd find on Instagram. I have the slide functionality working but the scroll menu does not appear underneath the navbar like it should. I've looked at [Implementing PageMenu / initializing view controllers from storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39339898/implementing-pagemenu-initializing-view-controllers-from-storyboard) but it doesn't really help my issue. I have also tried using the demo provided in the repo and customising it to my needs but then when I drag it on to my project it leaves out the scroll menu.

Here is my code in the viewControler:

```
    // Initialize view controllers to display and place in array
    var controllerArray : [UIViewController] = []

    let controller1 : TestTableViewController = TestTableViewController(nibName: "TestTableViewController", bundle: nil)
    controller1.parentNavigationController = self.navigationController
    controller1.title = "FAVOURITES"
    controllerArray.append(controller1)

    let controller2 : RecentsTableViewController = RecentsTableViewController(nibName: "RecentsTableViewController", bundle: nil)
    controller2.title = "RECIPES"
    controller2.parentNavigationController = self.navigationController
    controllerArray.append(controller2)


    // Customize menu (Optional)
    let parameters: [CAPSPageMenuOption] = [
        .menuItemSeparatorWidth(4.3),
        .scrollMenuBackgroundColor(UIColor.white),
        .viewBackgroundColor(UIColor(red: 247.0/255.0, green: 247.0/255.0, blue: 247.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)),
        .bottomMenuHairlineColor(UIColor(red: 33/255.0, green: 161/255.0, blue: 77/255.0, alpha: 1)),
        .selectionIndicatorColor(UIColor(red: 33/255.0, green: 161/255.0, blue: 77/255.0, alpha: 1.0)),
        .menuMargin(20.0),
        .menuHeight(40.0),
        .selectedMenuItemLabelColor(UIColor(red: 33/255.0, green: 161/255.0, blue: 77/255.0, alpha: 1.0)),
        .unselectedMenuItemLabelColor(UIColor(red: 40.0/255.0, green: 40.0/255.0, blue: 40.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)),
        .menuItemFont(UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Medium", size: 14.0)!),
        .useMenuLikeSegmentedControl(true),
        .menuItemSeparatorRoundEdges(true),
        .selectionIndicatorHeight(2.0),
        .menuItemSeparatorPercentageHeight(0.1)
    ]

    // Initialize scroll menu
    pageMenu = CAPSPageMenu(viewControllers: controllerArray, frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height), pageMenuOptions: parameters)

    // Optional delegate 
    pageMenu!.delegate = self

    self.view.addSubview(pageMenu!.view)
}
```

Please help me if you can. Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Replace this**

```
pageMenu = CAPSPageMenu(viewControllers: controllerArray, frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height), pageMenuOptions: parameters)
```

**With**

```
  pageMenu = CAPSPageMenu(viewControllers: controllerArray, frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 64, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height), pageMenuOptions: parameters)
```

You have to give y to 64 because status bar and navigation bar covers 64 points.

Comment: So it was literally just the y value? But then why is it in the demo, no y value was set? Either way, thank you so much!

Comment: Maybe they were not adding it on Navigation controller and Welcome :)